# Automatic calculation

Tags: android

I'm making an app where i want to automatically make an calculation.

the numbers **1 and 2** are **EditText**, number **3** is a **TextView**.
when i fill in the numbers **1 and 2**, i want it to **automatically sum up** and show a result in the **TextView**. in this example 1+2=3

**How to set up an activity for this**

i made an xml example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is add_two_numbers.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView android:text="First Number : "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView android:text="Second Number : "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView android:text="Result"
        android:id="@+id/textView_result"        
        android:textColor="#FF00FF"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />     
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is an Activity AddTwoNumbers.java

```
public class AddTwoNumbers extends Activity {

    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    TextView textViewResult;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
         super.onCreate(icicle); 
         setContentView(R.layout.add_two_numbers);

         editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
         textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);

         editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
             }

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                     int count) {
                 textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());             
             }

             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
             }             
         }); 

         editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                textViewResult.setText(addNumbers()); 

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
         }); 
    }

    private String addNumbers() {
        int number1; 
        int number2;
        if(editText1.getText().toString() != "" && editText1.getText().length() > 0) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number1 = 0;
        }
        if(editText2.getText().toString() != "" && editText2.getText().length() > 0) {
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number2 = 0;
        }

        return Integer.toString(number1 + number2);
    }
}
```

And I have tested it on 2.3 platform. It's working fine.

Comment: i get an error on:

**editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()**,
**editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()**,
**textView.setText(addNumbers());**

it says:
**editText1 can not be resolved**,
**editText2 can not be resolved**,
**textView can not be resolved**

Comment: when i want to fill in a number the app stops unexpectedly. i use android 3.1 emulator. **have you tried the code yourself.**

Comment: I had not thanked you yet but thanks. i'm using the code now for an bowling app, but how can i pretend the letter **x** (strike) to be number 10 and the **/** as a spare? and count the next turn double?

Comment: when i throw an strike i fill in an x as my score. when i do that it must add 10 points to de total points. when i throw my next turn it must double up the amount of pins i threw, for example 3 becomes 6.

Comment: Actually I am not getting your problem. Have you any example? If you don't mind paste some rough task example.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide a key listener to each of your EditTexts, such that after each key event you can refresh your values for the fields and present a new calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two TextViews and register a text changed [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) for them. whenever the text changes, you can validate input, do the calculation and update the display.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to raise any event automatically,you need to add the appropriate listeners to that view component

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                                        public void afterTextChanged(
                                                Editable arg0) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                        public void beforeTextChanged(
                                                CharSequence s, int start,
                                                int count, int after) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                        public void onTextChanged(
                                                CharSequence s, int start,
                                                int before, int count) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                    });
edittext2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                                        public void afterTextChanged(
                                                Editable arg0) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                        public void beforeTextChanged(
                                                CharSequence s, int start,
                                                int count, int after) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                        public void onTextChanged(
                                                CharSequence s, int start,
                                                int before, int count) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                    });
```